# Java Exception Stacktrace

Tags: java, android

I'm creating application and in this application I need to write all exceptions to file. I need to get line number of error and I'm using this to get line number:

```
entry.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
```

But I'm afraid, that stacktrace can be null. So my Question is - can stack trace be null?

Comment: why you wanted to write the just line number instead of full stack trace ?

Comment: @user2086174-just use e.getStackTrace

Answer (score 0):

If an Exception has been thrown, the

```
e.getStackTrace()
```

can't be null.

But why you don't use the std Java Logger or the android logger for Logging outputs?

Comment: what are the privileges of logger?

Comment: java.util.logging keeps you from having too much jars in your application and you have not to think about the formating of the Logger-outputs..
The severality is depending on configured types, so it is easy to keep the tracelog clean.

In general, at the top of every class, you should have

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( ClassName.class.getName() );

then, you can just use various facilities of the Logger class.